# DE Mixing Problem with decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am curious how to put together a balance equation which adds in a decay element.

For example:

> A large tank holds of a solution with chemical 'Z'. The flow rate of chemical Z entering the tank is equal to the flow rate exiting the tank.

From here I can work out that this works out to be the following balance equation:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dz_{\text{in}}}{dt} - \frac{dz_{\text{out}}}{dt}$$

But if the chemical is breaking down at a rate proportional to the amount of of chemical in the tank, how to I input that into the equation?

In other words, how to I add a 'decay' element to this balance equation, and how would I go about solving it?

Answer (score 1):

“The chemical is breaking down at a rate proportional to the amount of chemical in the tank” means that there is a term in $\frac{dz}{dt}$ proportional to $-z$.  The constant of proportionality would have to be determined from other data in the problem.

If $V$ is the volume of the tank, $v$ is the flow rate in and out of the tank, $c$ is the concentration of the solution coming in, and $k$ is the decay rate, then
$$
    \frac{dz}{dt} = cv - \frac{z}{V} v - k z = cv - \left(\frac{v}{V}+k\right)z
$$
Since $v$, $V$, $c$, and $k$ are all constant, the equation is separable (homogeneous, in fact).

Comment: That's what I thought. If I'm working this out with from concentration/flow rates and that decay element, the equation would look something like this right?: 

dC/dt =  C(in)F - CF - kCV.

And afterwards I can figure out the amount by multiplying by the volume?

If my thinking is correct so far, how do I create the general solution for C from dC/dt =  C(in)F - CF - kCV? I've looked everywhere online for more mixing problems which aren't the standard textbook type without the decay element. I can do the usual balance equation easily, but this stumps me 

I'm such a struggler with math.

Comment: I think your equation for $dC/dt$ is correct.  I usually recommend using the *amount* of $Z$ (what I called $z$) rather than the *concentration* of $Z$ (what you call $C$) as the dependent variable, but since the volume of the tank is constant, it doesn't matter much.  I'll edit the answer.